# Best way of aligning two sets of search results

Tags: html, css, list, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am building a web app which gets given search results, there are 2 kinds of results and I want to display them side by side in 2 lists or perhaps a grid.

One list my be bigger than the other so perhaps two lists are better. How to arrange them to be centred in the page but side by side.

Additionally how can I set the size of these boxes so the text wraps.

Sorry for the really basic questions Im very new to web development. Im using bootstrap 3 too by the way.

Comment: use a container and a 2 column grid

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
      <h3>List 2 Heading</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Result 1</li>
        <li>Result 2</li>
        ...
        <li>Result n</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
      <h3>List 2 Heading</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Result 1</li>
        <li>Result 2</li>
        ...
        <li>Result n</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The bootstrap framework will take care of all text wrapping within the columns for you, and lock the 2 columns in the middle of the page together with a few pixels padding between.  If you want a more boxed-in look, add `well` to the classes of the 2 `div` elements with `span6`, so `<div class="span6 well">`.

Comment: Thats great, how should i go about centering it. I could do text align centre and that works but it doesnt look nice. Can i have the whole thing centred but text to the left side of their respective containers still, should i use padding to do this? Additionally how do i make the container the li's are in a certain size so the text wraps?